# If a topology is generated by a metric d, then must the open sets in the metric space (X,d) belong to the topology?

Tags: general-topology

I understand that 'every metric space is a topological space', in the sense that the metric d generates the topology which is the collection of all open sets in (X,d). In this case open sets in the metric sense are equivalent to open sets in the topological sense.

I also understand that 'not every topological space is a metric space' in that not every topology can be generated by a metric.

Say a topological space *can* be generated by a metric, then does this mean that the open sets in (X,d) *must* belong to the topology and vice versa? Or am I missing something?

I ask this as my lecturer proved that the indiscrete space is not metrizable by: assuming it is and then finding an open set in (X,d) that does not belong to the topology, giving a contradiction. (Provided |X| is not 1).

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "yes".

Comment: This is basically the definition of “generate by.” Give a metric $d$ on $X$ there is a unique topology “generated by” the metric, defined by the open sets of the metric. There are no other topologies “generated by $d$“ by definition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you so much! I guess I was more just confused on the terminology. Just to clarify: does this mean that to show a topological space is not metrisable, you just need to find an open set in (X,d) that's not in the topology?

Comment: Well, you to show, for **every** metric, that there is either some open set in your topology not in the metric’s, **or** some open set in the metric’s that is not in your topology. @user898975

Comment: That said, the most common topologies $\tau$ which are not  metrizable *usually* have too few open sets - that is, given a metric, it is usually easier to find open sets in the metric  are not in $\tau.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*By definition*, the open sets in a topological space $(X,\tau)$ *are* the elements of $\tau$. This happens always, and not only when the topology is induced by a metric.

Concerning the last paragraph, I suppose that what your lectures did was something like this: if $x\in X$, and $X\ne\{x\}$, then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is not an open subset of $X$. However, if $d$ is any metric on $X$, then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is an open subset of $(X,d)$, since$$X\setminus\{x\}=\bigcup_{y\in X\setminus\{x\}}D_{d(y,x)}(y).$$What this proves is that there is a set which is not an open subset of $X$ with respect to the indiscrete topology, but which is open in $(X,d)$ for any metric $d$. So, the indiscrete topology is not induced by a metric.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mapping from the set of metrics on $X$ to the set of topologies on $X$: to a metric assign the topology $\mathcal{T}(d)$ generated by $d$. A topology $\mathcal{T}$ is metrisable precisely when it is in the image of this mapping (so there is a metric $d'$ on $X$ so that $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}(d')$.

Typically one shows a topology to be **non**-metrisable by noting that all topologies of the form $\mathcal{T}(d)$ are special and some topology does not obey one of them:

- all metrisable topologies are Hausdorff and perfectly normal.
- all metrisable topologies are paracompact.
- all metrisable topologies that are separable are also second countable, hereditarily Lindelöf etc.
- all metrisable topologies are first countable.

And the indicrete topology on a space with two or more points is not Hausdorff so cannot be metrisable.

There are theorems that exactly characterise a topology that is metrisable in just finitely many properties to check (and that do not mention metric). Maybe your course will cover them later.

Comment: I'm only really studying the basics right now so this is a bit too advanced for me, but thank you anyway!